# Como pasar Jquery a coffescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

Hola devs estoy tratando de pasar este codigo jquery funcional a coffeescript pero no me lee nada.

```
$('.only-numbers-money').on('blur change input', function() {
  $(this).val(function(i, input) {
    input = input.replace(/\D/g, '');
    return (input / 100).toFixed(2);
  });
}).trigger('blur');
```

Este es mi codigo coffeescript

```
$('.only-numbers-money').on("blur change input", () ->
 $(this).val((i, input)-> 
 input = input.replace(/\D/g, "");
 return (input / 100).toFixed(2);
  );
).trigger("blur");
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/coffee-script/1.7.1/coffee-script.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <input class="only-numbers-money" />
  <script type="text/coffeescript">
$('.only-numbers-money').on('blur change input', ->
  $(this).val (i, input) ->
    input = input.replace(/\D/g, '')
    (input / 100).toFixed 2
  return
).trigger 'blur'
  </script>
</body>
```

Si no eres experto en el cambio de sintaxis puedes usar [js2coffee](http://js2.coffee/).

Como veras lo que te falto es que lo que va dentro de una funcion en javascript, en cofee se indenta, por eso si tu codigo le agregas la identacion funciona como:

```
$('.only-numbers-money').on("blur change input", () ->
 $(this).val((i, input)-> 
  input = input.replace(/\D/g, ""); // indentado
  return (input / 100).toFixed(2); // indentado paps
  );
).trigger("blur");
```